# How do I add the Arab League flag as language?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I can't find a flag of the Arab League in Drupal. How do I add this flag as language? It isn't showing in the languages' list.

Comment: do you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a flag as a language, if you can add a new language go to `YOUR_SITE/admin/config/regional/language/`add choose the new language if your language is not listed you can add a Custom language (See at the bottom of the page the collapsed option).

And if you want to use a flag for your language you can install the [Language Icons](https://www.drupal.org/project/languageicons) module. Then go to the folder (in your server) `YOUR_SITE/sites/all/modules/languageicons/flags` and add the flag for your new language, you need to use as a name YOUR_LANGUAGE_CODE.png